# Lack of permissions in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell

I created C:/Users/homedir/Documents/Python. Windows automatically
puts that in OneDrive's path.  Is this causing the permission errors?

```
d@LAPTOP-M0R87BQ6 MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/Python/twilio-python-main (main)
$ python3 setup.py install
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

# The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-9920.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\
```

Is the only problem I need to create the directory (or modify setup.py to install in Python's path elsewhere)?

```
Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.
```

I am the Admin for this machine, I'm in the Group Administrators.  There is no higher root on my machine.  I opened a PowerShell as an Admin and ran the python interpreter.  Still insufficient permissions.  Looking at Windows Explorer I am Owner of all the files.

The error says: "If you do not have administrative access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHON PATH environment variable."

```
For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

in cmd windows try taking ownership of WindowsApps folder and ensure the properties are inherited by its subfolders

```
takeown /f \"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" && icacls \"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" /grant administrators:F
```